# PHP - Getting variable data from another function

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, pdo

I'm trying to encrypt the password with AES-256, for that I have the key and the method in the database. My problem it's that I was using mysqli and that works very well, but now I was making with PDO else mysqli and creating functions.

The functions work well without the function Encryption. So there is my code.

```
<?php 

class DWLib {

public function Register($u_name, $u_email, $u_pass) {
        try {
            $db = DB();
            $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(u_fname, u_lname, u_name, u_email, u_pass, u_rank) VALUES ('','',:username,:email,:password,'1')");
            $query->bindParam("username", $u_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("email", $u_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            global $password;

            $password = substr(hash('sha256', $password, true), 0, 32);

            global $method;

            $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

            $encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($u_pass, $method, $password, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));

            $query->bindParam("password", $encrypted, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
            return $db->lastInsertId();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

  public function Encryption($password, $method) 
    {
        try {
            $db = DB();
            $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM encryption");
            $query->execute();
            if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $password = $row["password"];
                    $method = $row["method"];
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I tried to use return, but keeps not working...

Comment: why aren't you using `password_hash() / password_verify()`?

Comment: because SHA isn't encryption, it's a one-way hash function. AES (Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a symmetric encryption standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `$password` and `$method`,

you have to pass them by reference `&` :

```
public function Encryption(&$password, &$method) {
```

**EDIT**

If you have to pass variables from functions, you have to use properties. Add `private $password;` and `private $method;` and use them with `$this->password` and `$this->method` :

```
class DWLib {
    private $password;
    private $method; 

    public function function_1() {
       // ...
          $this->password = "something";
          $this->method = "something else";
       // ...
    }

    public function function_2() {
       // ...
          var_dump($this->password) ;
          var_dump($this->method) ; 
       // ...
    }

 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the data (password and method) from the table and use that data in the other function to encrypt the password.

Comment: keeps, not getting the data from the other function. 

I need to get the data from the function

    public function function_1() {
       // ...
          $this->password = $row["password"];
   $this->method = $row["method"];
       // ...
    }

to the function that have $password = substr(hash('sha256', $this->password, true), 0, 32);   That will be something like this right?: $password = substr(hash('sha256', var_dump($this->password), true), 0, 32);